# Codeception - Accessing localhost using Dockerized Webdriver

Tags: docker, selenium, webdriver, codeception

I'm currently having this issue:

```
                                                                                                                                       
  [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException] unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)
```

What I'm trying to do is for my dockerized webdriver which is on `localhost:4444` access `localhost:7070` which contains one of services that was port-forwarded thru OpenShift CLI and is accessible locally using any browsers.
``

I run the dockerized webdriver using this command:

`docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome:4.1.0-20211123`

Here is the environment variable:

```
modules:
  config:
      WebDriver:
          url: http://localhost:4444
          browser: chrome
          capabilities:
              chromeOptions:
                  args: ["no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu"]
```

Here is the stepdefinition:

```
    public function access7070Site() {
        $this->acceptanceTester -> amOnUrl('http://localhost:7070');
    }
```

When I try to access external sites, the webdriver can access it, however, when I access other localhost port its having the Connection Refused issue. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Read here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: Tried it but I still got the connection refused ;(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it with docker, I suggest to use `docker-compose` to do so.

Here is a working `docker-compose.yaml` which is using your project in parallel to selenium and takes care of the networking between the containers:

```yaml
---
version: '3.4'

services:
  php:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - selenium
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app:rw,cached

  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:4
    shm_size: 2gb
    container_name: selenium
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
      - "7900:7900"
    environment:
      - VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1
      - SCREEN_WIDTH=1920
      - SCREEN_HEIGHT=1080
```

after you created this file, you can simply run `docker-compose up -d` to start the containers and type this to start your webdriver tests:

```
docker-compose exec php vendor/bin/codecept run
```

And one nice feature is, that you can connect the selenium container via VNC and see, what the test is actually doing: http://localhost:7900/